# How to pass user data into vue in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I am able to log my user data in console log,
if I try to display the data on Contalist page it dosen't return anything. Please, I am new to using vue I just need to implement it to my projects. Here my php controller and vue component files,
THANKS.

Controller php file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\PostRequest;
use App\Models\User;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    public function getMessages(){

        return view('user/message'); //response()->json($contacts);
    }
    public function getContact(){
        $email = Auth::user()->email;
        $contacts = PostRequest::with('user')->where([['email', $email]])->orderBy('id','DESC')->first()->user;
        return response()->json($contacts);
       
    }

}
```

Vue ChatComponet

```
    <template>
      <div class="chat-app">
         <Conversation/>
         <ContactsList :contacts="contacts"/>
       </div>
     </template>

     <script>
         import Conversation from './Conversation';
         import ContactsList from './ContactsList';

        export default {
           props: {
              user: {
                  type: Object,
                  required: true
                }
             },
           data(){
           return{
               messages: [],
               contacts: []
           }
        },
        mounted() {
           console.log(this.user);
            axios.get('/user/contacts')
                .then((response) => {
                   // console.log(response.data);
                    this.contacts = response.data;
                });
            },
             components: {Conversation, ContactsList}
         }
      </script>
```

Vue ContactlistComponet

```
    <template>
    <div class="contacts-list">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.id.user">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img :src="contact.user.reqPhoto" :alt="contact.name.user">
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <p class="name">{{contact.user.name}}</p>
                <p class="email">{{contact.user.email}}</p>
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        contacts: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Route

```
    Route::get('/user/contacts', [ChatController::class, ('getContact')]);
```

the names match i just had typo while typing in stackoverflow, i have errors in console app.js:38946

> [Vue warn]: Invalid default value for prop "messages": Props with type Object/Array must use a factory function to return the default value. found in --->  at resources/js/components/Conversation.vue  at resources/js/components/ChatComponent.vue  _
> app.js:38946 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')" found in --->  at resources/js/components/ContactsList.vue  at resources/js/components/ChatComponent.vue  app.js:40222 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: I suspect it is returning something, however because you've not implemented a `catch` in your `axios` call it appears as though nothing is being returned. Additionally, you don't need the brackets `(` `)` around your action.

Comment: If you log what Axios is getting as `response.data`, what is the value?

Comment: axios is getting the selected user data, which i need the login user to chat with, but i can't display his information on the page @matiaslauriti

Comment: @Peppermintology have implemented the catch still same no error

Comment: @Barnabaskoloz can you show us your data? Also, if you open the console, do you see any Javascript error? It seems the issue is on the `Contactlist` component. One more thing, on your template you use `ContactsList` but here on StackOverflow you mentioned the file to be `ContactlistComponet`, so do they match on the definition?

Comment: @matialslauriti the names match i just had typo while typing in stackoverflow, i have errors in console **app.js:38946 [Vue warn]: Invalid default value for prop "messages": Props with type Object/Array must use a factory function to return the default value.

found in

---> <Conversation> at resources/js/components/Conversation.vue
       <ChatApp> at resources/js/components/ChatComponent.vue
         <Root>** _

Comment: **app.js:38946 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"

found in

---> <ContactsList> at resources/js/components/ContactsList.vue
       <ChatApp> at resources/js/components/ChatComponent.vue
         <Root>** _app.js:40222 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')_

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass `:messages` prop to this `<Conversation />` component like this

`<Conversation :messages=messages/>`

lastly can you please check, in your `ul` where you are iterating the list of contacts, what kind of data you are receiving.

Comment: in the ul am still receiving the logged in user and the correspondence to chat with but accessible only in console log